# unconfigured columnfamily error on consecutive execute calls (CQL)

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, column-family

I'm using the [cassandra python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) for datastax's distro. mah codez...

```
from cassandra.io.libevreactor import LibevConnection
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['some ip addr'])
cluster.connection_class = LibevConnection
```

fails:

```
   session = cluster.connect('demodb')
   session.execute("INSERT INTO colFamName(attr1, attr2) VALUES ('123jkd', 'sdflkj')")
   session.execute("SELECT attr1 FROM colFamName")
```

passes:

```
   session = cluster.connect('demodb')
   session.execute("INSERT INTO colFamName(attr1, attr2) VALUES ('123jkd', 'sdflkj')")
   session.set_keyspace('demodb')
   session.execute("SELECT attr1 FROM colFamName")
```

error:

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cassandra/cluster.py", line 995, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2195, in result
cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured columnfamily <my_columnfamily_name>"
```

consecutive session.execute calls work as long as I have 'reset' the keyspace since the last session.execute call. I should not have to reset this after every session.execute call.

thoughts?  (I have already filed an issue in github, and will update when I get a response)

Comment: Really need to see actual queries and KS / CF names to determine the problem here.

Comment: @davis-dulin have you tried without ``cluster.connection_class = LibevConnection``?

Comment: yes. it did not change anything : /